# Error in loading image_dataset_from_directory in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network

This is the code 
from https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_from_scratch/

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

# generate a dataset 
image_size = (180,180)
batch_size = 32

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "PetImages",
    validation_split = 0.2,
    subset = "training",
    seed = 1337,
    image_size = image_size,
    batch_size = batch_size,
)
```

Error is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-bb7f2d14bf63> in <module>
      3 batch_size = 32
      4 
----> 5 train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
      6     "PetImages",
      7     validation_split = 0.2,

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.preprocessing' has no attribute 'image_dataset_from_directory'
```

Any smallest detail which I am overlooking now?

Comment: Which tf version is this?

Comment: the version is 2.2.0

Answer (score 10):

v2.5.0
I got the same error using that code:

```
tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(...)
```

changing it to:

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(...)
```

fix my problem

Comment: I use 2.4.0, and it was solved the same way. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 9):

It has been addressed under [this issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-io/issues/12).

`The specific function (tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory) is not available under TensorFlow v2.1.x or v2.2.0 yet. It is only available with the tf-nightly builds and is existent in the source code of the master branch.`

Too bad they didn't indicate it anywhere on site. Better to use `flow_from_directory` for now. Or switch to `tf-nightly` and carry on.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem. When I upgraded the TensorFlow version to 2.3.0, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

### **The `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` function is not found because it does not exist in the tf.keras.utils module.**

---

The correct function to load a dataset of images from a directory is

**`tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory`**

This function is part of the `tf.keras.preprocessing` module, not `tf.keras.utils`.

**Syntax**

```
import tensorflow as tf
dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory, # Path to the directory
    labels='inferred', # Automatically infers labels from directory structure
    label_mode='int', # Labels are integers
    color_mode='rgb', # Images are color
    batch_size=32, # Size of the batches of data
    image_size=(256, 256), # Size to resize images to
)
```

Please replace `directory` with the path to your image directory. The function will automatically infer labels from the directory structure. For example, if your directory is structured as `directory/dog/xxx.png` and `directory/cat/yyy.png`, the function will assign the label `‘dog’` to `xxx.png` and `‘cat’` to `yyy.png`. The labels will be represented as integers (0 for ‘dog’ and 1 for ‘cat’ in this case).

The images will be resized to `256x256 pixels` and they will be in `color (RGB)`. The function will return a `tf.data.Dataset` object.